# Dynamic resolver in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have an nginx config that varies from prod to dev.  I'm currently using `map` to tease out the differences based on `$host` and `$server_name`, but the one thing I can't seem to make variable is the resolver.  As it stands, I have to set `${RESOLVER}` and replace it during runtime with `envsubst` like so:

```
CMD /bin/bash -c "envsubst '\$RESOLVER'  < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

with a config file (snippet) like

```
location /auth_website {
  internal;

  ${RESOLVER}

  set $backend_upstream "http://$upstream_host/blah/$uuid";
  proxy_pass $backend_upstream;

  include 'includes/common_auth.conf';

}
```

is there a way to set a resolver dynamically, based on the `$host`, `$server_name` or an env var within the file?  It feels like no, but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having this problem too and it's surprising that there's no obvious way round it.